# Ошибки компоновщика LNK2005 LNK1169

Tags: c++, компоновщик

Решил попробовать поэкспериментировать создать проект, записав функцию в отдельный файл, однако произошла для меня неведомая ошибка. Тестировал я это на нескольких компиляторах и ошибка та же, следовательно проблема в моем коде.

**Source.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
#include "func.cpp"

int main() {
    int num, expotent;
    std::cout << "Enter the number: ";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << "Enter the expotent";
    std::cin >> expotent;
    std::cout << exponentiation(num, expotent);
}
```

**Header.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

long long int exponentiation(int x, int y);

#endif
```

**func.cpp**

```
#ifndef FUNC_CPP
#define FUNC_CPP
#include "Header.h"

long long int exponentiation(int x, int y) {
    if (y == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    for (int c = 1; c == y; c++) {
        x *= x;
    }
    return x;
}

#endif // !FUNC_CPP
```

Как я понял ошибка происходит из-за того, что функция exponentiation определяется несколько раз, хотя почему это происходит, понять не могу.

**Подробности ошибки:**

```
LNK1169 обнаружен многократно определенный символ - один или более  deleeeeteeee    C:\Users\Ivan\source\repos\deleeeeteeee\Debug   C:\Users\Ivan\source\repos\deleeeeteeee\Debug\deleeeeteeee.exe  1   
LNK2005 "__int64 __cdecl exponentiation(int,int)" (?exponentiation@@YA_JHH@Z) уже определен в func.obj  deleeeeteeee    C:\Users\Ivan\source\repos\deleeeeteeee\deleeeeteeee
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Беда в том, что вы зачем-то включаете `func.cpp` в `source.cpp`:

```
#include "func.cpp"
```

В результате у вас есть `exponentiation` и в `func.obj`, и в `source.obj`, и компоновщик не знает, какой предпочесть.

Уберите указанную строку из `source.cpp`.